# Using a loop to .setdefault on Dict Creates Nested Dict

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to understand why

```
tree = {}

def add_to_tree(root, value_string):
    """Given a string of characters `value_string`, create or update a
    series of dictionaries where the value at each level is a dictionary of
    the characters that have been seen following the current character.
    """
    for character in value_string:
        root = root.setdefault(character, {})

add_to_tree(tree, 'abc')
```

creates `{'a': {'b': {'c': {}}}}`

while

```
root = {}

root.setdefault('a', {})
root.setdefault('b', {})
root.setdefault('c', {})
```

creates `{'a': {}, 'b': {}, 'c': {}}`

What is putting us into the assigned dict value on each iteration of the loop?

Comment: Your second part of the code is not giving the result you claim, if I copy paste it in my python interpreter I get an empty dict back. What do you want your end-result dict to look, can you post that?

Comment: @dtheodor thanks, man. pasted wrong code. updated now.

Answer (score 2):

[`root.setdefault(character, {})`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) returns `root[character]` if `character` is a key in `root` or it returns the empty dict `{}`. It is the same as `root.get(character, {})` except that it also assigns `root[character] = {}` if `character` is not already a key in `root`.

---

```
root = root.setdefault(character, {})
```

reassigns `root` to a new dict if `character` is not already a key in the original `root`.

```
In [4]: root = dict()

In [5]: newroot = root.setdefault('a', {})

In [6]: root
Out[6]: {'a': {}}

In [7]: newroot
Out[7]: {}
```

---

In contrast, using `root.setdefault('a', {})` without reassigning its return value to `root` works:

```
tree = {}

def add_to_tree(root, value_string):
    """Given a string of characters `value_string`, create or update a
    series of dictionaries where the value at each level is a dictionary of
    the characters that have been seen following the current character.
    """
    for character in value_string:
        root.setdefault(character, {})

add_to_tree(tree, 'abc')
print(tree)
# {'a': {}, 'c': {}, 'b': {}}
```

Comment: you're right. i updated the second set of code to what i meant. i think the answer i'm looking for has something to do with `state`, so that each time through the loop we're getting "but wait, there's more" and adding to the returned result. so when we get to `.setdefault('b', {})`, that is actually assigned to the `{}` in the what is assigned to `root` at the 'a' space and again one level deeper with 'c'. is `state` the word i'm looking for?

Comment: Yes, it has to do with the "state of `root`", though I think most would just say the "value of `root`". You may want to step through the code using the [online visualizer](http://bit.ly/1m87lf5). Then modify it to see what `root = root.setdefault(...)` does.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who is as slow as me. The answer to, "Why does the (above) function produce `{'a': {'b': {'c': {}, 'd': {}}}}` and not `{'a': {}, 'b': {}, 'c': {}}`?" is:

Because we’re looping within a function and reassigning the the result to root each time, it’s kind of like in the TV infomercials where they keep saying, “but wait! there’s more!”. So when .setdefault gets called on 'a', before that gets returned, it’s result, `{'a': {}}` is held {inside the loop} while it’s run on 'b', which yields `{'b': {}}`, within `{'a': {}}` and that is held to the side and `{'a': {}}` is run, then the whole thing is returned from the loop and applied to tree. Note that each time, what is actually returned by .setdefault IS the default, which in this case is `{}`. Here is a [Python Visualizer](http://pythontutor.com/iframe-embed.html#code=def+add_to_tree%28root,+value_string%29%3A%0A++++for+character+in+value_string%3A%0A++++++++root+%3D+root.setdefault%28character,+%7B%7D%29%0A++++++++++++%0Atree+%3D+%7B%7D%0A%0Aadd_to_tree%28tree,+%27abc%27%29&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&drawParentPointers=false&textReferences=false&showOnlyOutputs=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=[]&curInstr=11&codeDivWidth=350&codeDivHeight=400) illustration of the process.